# Access Resolved parameters from a state without Controller inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I'm refactoring all my code to implement Top Level Directives as described in this article [Scaling Angular Apps](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/sane-scalable-angular-apps-are-tricky-but-not-impossible-lessons-learned-from-paypal-checkout-c5320558d4ef) and I'm not sure how to access my resolved values:

```
$stateProvider
            .state('login', {
                url      : '/login',
                template : '<sr-login-view></sr-login-view>'
            })
            .state('main', {
                url      : '/main',
                template : '<sr-main-view></sr-main-view>',
                resolve  : {
                    directiveConfig : function (Directives) {
                        return Directives.getConfig('mainScreen');
                    }
                }
            });
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('ElectronClient')
    .directive('srMainView', function (directiveConfig //doesn't work) {
        return {
            restrict    : 'E',
            require     : 'srMainScreen',
            scope       : {},
            templateUrl : 'source/app/directives/main/main_view.html',
            controller  : function ($scope, directiveConfig //doesn't work) {

                //code

            },
            link : {
                post : function (scope, element, attributes, mainViewController) {

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Is there some workaround to this? The whole point of having "Top Level" directives is to not define the Controller in the state but it seems the resolve parameter is passed only to the controller attached to that state

Comment: add controller on `main` state and then pass the resolve `directiveConfig`  to directive isolated scope.

Comment: I was trying to find any other way

Comment: But i guess i'll have to resort to that ... :p

Comment: What does Directives.getConfig look like?

Comment: What do you mean? It returns a promise. If resolved: the resolved data is a json objetc

Comment: Please, post some code. It may be suitable to make directiveConfig a reusable service. Or it may not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The whole point of having "Top Level" directives is to not define the Controller in the state

Yeah, that's the point, but why? So that you can leverage this:

> The moment I need a reusable child component for my page which isn’t associated with a route, I’m stuck using a different pattern altogether, and my app becomes harder to reason about.

Now using `resolve` would defeat that purpose, since depending on how you call your directive, some will have `directiveConfig` available for injection and some will not. Which means that you **will** be using different patterns depending on how a directive is used.

To stay consistent with what that article suggests, I guess it's best to stay away from resolving values in your routes and resolving them in the controller.